# Аналог классу OleDbConnection из библиотеки System.Data.OleDb в NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Какой есть аналог классу OleDbConnection из библиотеки System.Data.OleDb в NET Core 5?
Ранее для работы с Excel пользовался довольно удобным классом OleDbConnection из библиотеки System.Data.OleDb, а в NET Core 5 этот объект уже отсутствует, хотя саму библиотеку Data.OleDb подключить можно.

Comment: В обычном .NET Framework содержится огромное количество классов. В .NET Core их нужно устанавливать в виде пакетов. Поэтому подключайте нугет-пакет, как указано в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно почему вы считаете что его там нет.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb

> System.Data.OleDb 5.0.0
>
> Provides a collection of classes for OLEDB.
>
> Commonly Used Types: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbTransaction

также можно наблюдать [тут](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0/5.0.0.md)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Ведать у меня в проект подтянулась старая версия, сейчас загрузил новую через Нугет - все появилось

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir - нет, у вас не могла подтянуться старая версия. Потому что в .net core нет по умолчанию никаких версий.